# How to define dictionary fields with flask_restplus to be used in go code generated with swagger codegen?

Tags: go, swagger-codegen, flask-restplus

I have used swagger CLI to generate go code to call my flask app. swagger codegen converts `fields.Raw` type defined with `flask_restplus` model  to `*interface{}` in go

assigning the value to the field with *interface{} type in go returns back

> prog.go:18:26: cannot use notebook_spec_secrets (type
>   map[string]string) as type *interface {} in assignment:   *interface {}
>   is pointer to interface, not interface

You can test it here
https://play.golang.org/p/sFE9Qr-72_G

A quick and dirty fix will be changing the generated code by swagger cli and change

> NotebookSpec *interface{}

to

> NotebookSpec interface{}

1. Is it possible to cast dictionary to *interface{} in go? (my google search shows a pointer to the interface in go is invalid and logically is not correct )
2. How to define a dictionary field with [flask-restplus](https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/flask_restplus/fields.html)

```
run_definition = api.model('Run definition',
                           {

                               'notebook_spec_secrets':
                               fields.Raw(required=False,
                                          example={
                                              "eventhub_source_cs": "Endpoint=sb://xxxx.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=xxxx;SharedAccessKey=xxxx=;EntityPath=sourceeh",
                                              "eventhub_destination_cs": "Endpoint=sb://xxxx.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=xxxx;SharedAccessKey=xxxx=;EntityPath=desteh",
                                              "adl2_destination_oauth2_clientid": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                                              "adl2_destination_oauth2_clientsecret": "xxxx=",
                                              "adl2_destination_oauth2_tenantid": "xxxx=",
                                              "adl2_destination_cs": "abfss://<file-system-name>@<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net/folder1",
                                          })})
```

Comment: Could you post a minimal snippet of what swagger generates where you see the problem?

Comment: It's here => https://play.golang.org/p/sFE9Qr-72_G

Comment: Adding an answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not sure why it generates a pointer to an interface, but can still assign to it by explicitly casting your map to `interface{}` and then taking the address of 
that:

```
notebook_spec_secrets := map[string]string{
    "eventhub_source_cs":                   "1",
    "eventhub_destination_cs":              "2",
    "adl2_destination_oauth2_clientid":     "3",
    "adl2_destination_oauth2_clientsecret": "4",
    "adl2_destination_oauth2_tenantid":     "5",
    "adl2_destination_cs":                  "6",
}

var nssi interface{} = notebook_spec_secrets
definition.NotebookSpec = &nssi
```

https://play.golang.org/p/rHrMH_jF_oS